# What software should I use to write books, which can be exported to Lulu and CreateSpace?

Tags: publishing, validation, metadata

I currently use PagePlus X6 to typeset books. It has the capability to export to `.pdf` files and `.epub` files. However, the generated files are being rejected by Lulu and CreateSpace.
Is there an alternative I can use which can prepare files for Lulu and CreateSpace easily?

Some sample error messages received from Lulu:

> Your eBook has been rejected for improper capitalization. The first letter of all words in the title, subtitle and author name should be capitalized, except for the following words: a, an, and, for, from, of, or, the, to. The first and last word of the title and subtitle should always be capitalized.
>
> Your title should be the very first line of your document, with no blank lines or images above it, styled as Heading 1, to replace the broken link in your NCX. Style text as Heading 1 by selecting the text, then clicking “Heading 1” in the style toolbar.

Comment: Lulu advertises a free converter for Word and RTF to ePub - have you tried that? Also, you could try opening the file in the Calibre ePub editor to see what the problem is. My bet is that your software is creating files that are just slightly off and it might be easier to fix the files than to learn an entirely new software package.

Comment: Can you display the error message?

Comment: I have added the error messages now.
The converter from Word to ePub works but the requirement is to change design to very simple formatting. I lose the capability of rich formatting and also the beautiful .pdf file.
Ideally I would love the capability of write once and publish everywhere.
Calibre does not show any problem. It is only Lulu which replies back after 6 weeks with vague error messages.

Comment: Have you not validated the epub?  All epubs should be validated if you are going to sell them and Calibre wont show a problem because it is not meant for production but for personal usage.  Also, you will not be able to publish one file for all because each book may render differently on devices and certain features have to be coded certain ways.

Comment: @Matt_2.0: Your comment is a very good one; perhaps it could be an answer or even a self-answered question. "How do I validate an epub?" is a question that I expect we will see here somewhat regularly.

Comment: I planned to make a few Questions and Answers on this topic because sadly in the digital book world this is a topic not considered but it should be taken with up-most importance.

Comment: @Matt_2.0: I opened the file with Calibre and it opened fine, that led me to believe that all is OK. Apparently I need some other tool to validate the file, I guess.

Comment: Why does this have close votes?

Comment: Because it is too broad and cannot be correctly answered till we can have a look at the files.  Just because calibre can open an ebook doesnt mean a retailor will except it.  You should not and some will noy allow an ebook with errors to be loaded to their platform just like in this case.

Comment: You probably should drop Lulu as they cannot support all authors with the rules they are having. I have **all lowercase words** in my full name, as has e.g. the author of the published book [Justine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquis_de_Sade)

Answer (score 3):

For CreateSpace you essentially need to provide a PDF and do the layout by combining your output with images [in the form of PDF output](https://www.createspace.com/Help/Book/Artwork.do). To conform to their formats, you would still need a template for the editing software that you use, that generates a PDF that can be merged with such templates (and not come into the margins as they warn you not to).

The CreateSpace forums give some, but IMHO not very much more helpful tips (e.g. [here](https://forums.createspace.com/en/community/thread/2539))

It looks like CreateSpace is more reader-customer oriented and not so much bookwriter-customer, I had more help from the publisher for the single book that I helped typeset that made the shelves, and I was the first generating electronic input (from LaTex) for them.

Comment: That doesn't answer the error.  His error is caused by incorrect metadata and a bad link in the ePub.  The OP will get the same error even if he submits it as a `.pdf` file.  If the bookmark is wrong, my past experience, it will generate the same incorrect link in the `.ncx` file.

Comment: @Gramps the error you efer to is Lulu specific, my answer is on how to create acceptable CreateSpace material. My only experience (as a reader) with LuLu is that I had an error in my Apache config for two years because of sloppy output formatting.

Comment: its not LuLu specific.  The same errors are both generated by many other platforms but the OP didnt ask for those.  If you want me to edit my answer with examples we should edit the OP's question to extend on that and stay on-topic.

Comment: @Gramps, don't think that is necessary, the OP seems to have lost interest in the site (just looked up his profile).

Answer (score 1):

> Your eBook has been rejected for improper capitalization. The first
>   letter of all words in the title, subtitle and author name should be
>   capitalized, except for the following words: a, an, and, for, from,
>   of, or, the, to. The first and last word of the title and subtitle
>   should always be capitalized.

This error is because you have a title or author in the wrong format while sending in the metadata:

- WRONG = "lorem ipsum"
- WRONG = "LOREM IPSUM"
- RIGHT = "Lorem Ipsum"

> Your title should be the very first line of your document, with no
>   blank lines or images above it, styled as Heading 1, to replace the
>   broken link in your NCX. Style text as Heading 1 by selecting the
>   text, then clicking “Heading 1” in the style toolbar.

This is a known issue if you use a program like Calibre, in regards to incorrect bookmarks to incorrect locations, and several platforms will issue a refund on your title if you do not check your bookmarks.

I would suggest if you are using any tool to generate an ePub you should ALWAYS navigate and test your ePub and validate it through a current validator.  A validator I recommend to people that experience ePub issues is [IDPF](http://validator.idpf.org/).

As stated by Anthon you can submit a `.pdf` file but your metadata could still be incorrect and the bookmarks incorrect so you may still get the same error.

- Reference: [The use of metadata in PDF files](http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/metadata)
- Reference: [Adding metadata to document properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c34.w.html)

Another key note make sure your fonts are embedded in the `.pdf` file if you are going to submit it VIA `.pdf` because you will get an error.  To check:

- Open `.pdf` file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- Click Tab <kbd>FONTS</kbd>
- Review accordingly

Comment: the OP is not only about metadata. The message quoted from LuLu writes about "the first line of your document"

Comment: That's an error when generating an incorrect bookmarked title, but again, as stated in my comment above to the OP, I would need to see the file to properly see what the issue is.